Need change of font colour "red" of column "C" Rows no: 4-5-6-7, if value of merged cell "D" column get negative
Need change of font colour "red" of column "C"  Rows no: 4-5-6-7, if value of  merged cell "D" column get negative


Any reason not to use simple conditional formatting for that?

I need code in VBA, i already merged cell and changed font color by excel vba but not able to change colour of C or B column

Please share the code that applies the formatting to column A so we can build on it.

Assuming rngCell refers to a range (cell or cells) in Column A, you can change the font color of Column D by using rngCell.Offset(, 3).Font.Color = vbRed.

Okay, if you insist on VBA.
When you merge cells, the value is stored in the first (=top/left) cell of the merged range (D2, D4). All cells of a merged range can be accessed using the property MergeArea - which is again a Range object.
When you look at your data in Row 3, the value you want to read is in D2. You can get this by using Range("D3").MergeArea.Cells(1)
So your code would be
With ActiveSheet
    Dim row As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        .Cells(row, 1).Resize(1, 4).Font.Color = IIf(.Cells(row, 4).MergeArea.Cells(1) < 0, vbRed, vbBlack)
    Next
End


Thanks a lot, great, this was my first question on your site, and get answered, i m happy
